# How to have a "spongy" height on list elements

Tags: css, dynamic, height

I'm looking for a way, in pure CSS, to have dynamic "spongy" height elements

You have a list of a set height, and depending on the number of list elements, their combined height takes up a total of 100% of the height of the UL

e.g. 1 element is 100% height, 2 elements both 50%, 3 elements at 33% a piece, etc...

I've set a min-height so it doesn't go under a certain size, but the problem I'm having is that elements 2-n are being pushed completely out of their UL by the first element (it hogs the entire 100% height) - instead of being spongy like I want.

Maybe I'm missing some attribute that forces the list elements to stay inside their container, or some magic attribute that makes the list elements shrink down until they get to their min-height?

Driving me crazy.

Here is a fiddle to try: http://jsfiddle.net/CrudOMatic/nYMp7/

CSS:

```
.container { height: 104px; }
.entry-value {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 104px;
    max-height: 104px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ffd300;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.entry-value li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 23px;
    max-height: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid #000000 1px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="entry-value">
        <li>Text 1</li>
        <li>Text 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you care about supporting older browsers? You can do this easily with flexbox

Comment: not really, but it would be ideal - heck, I'm already ruling out IE8

Comment: eh, I'd have to say no to flexbox - the support is abysmal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this trick, which uses the relation between first and last item..
(*a rule for each number of rows is required*)

```
/* 1 item */
.entry-value li:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    height: 100%;
}

/* 2 items */
.entry-value li:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.entry-value li:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ li {
    height: 50%;
}

/* 3 items */
.entry-value li:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.entry-value li:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ li {
    height: 33.3333%;
}

/* 4 items */
.entry-value li:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.entry-value li:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ li {
    height: 25%;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nYMp7/1/

---

(*credits to [Clever lists with CSS3 selectors](http://andr3.net/blog/post/142) and [Styling elements based on sibling count](http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/)*)